# SagePay returning successful but failing INVALID_SIGNATURE PPro

Tags: php, payment, opayo

We have a long-standing SagePay integration on a mid-range e-commerce.
We're using the iframe integration and PPro (in this instance) although PayPal and card payments are also accepted. On this one order (out of tens-of-thousands), we have the following:

SagePay shows a failed payment at first, and logs show:

> Response received: HttpResponse
>
> ```
> {body='Status=INVALID RedirectUrl=https://XXXXXXXXXXINVALID_SIGNATURE StatusDetail=Signature not valid - goodbye ', statusCode=200, statusMessage='OK'}
> ```

However, our call to the API passed, no errors whatsoever, and we marked as a success.

> [Status] => OK
>
> [StatusDetail] => 0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.

The payment did, a few days later, process, via PPro.
I'm guessing:

1. User submitted payment details
2. Payment provisionally accepted (we get the go ahead)
3. WE confirm the order, mark it as accepted etc..
4. SagePay try and connect to PPro (or vice-versa), this fails with a signature error on first attempt.
5. SagePay log this error mark the payment as failed.
6. SagePay retries to connect to PPro, works.
7. SagePay completes payment, all is well.

I don't have access to the SP account and trying to debug from limited info. The order was a few months ago and we no longer have any logs and I have no way to replicate this.

Thoughts?

Cheers,
James